# C# and Html: How to implement an already created C# class for windows form to html?

Tags: c#, html, webforms, textbox, event-handling

Beginner here,

I have asked a similar question and I apologize if my terminology is incorrect.
I have this windows app form project that has basically a class with five fields and another class that makes the form do stuff like change text inside a textbox when a button is clicked. I used the form designer to test out the code to make sure it works and it did now I believe all I have to do is replace code that says "Textbox.Text" with it's html equivalent and place methods inside html button event handlers.

I am working as a team so I have to understand other people's html code. To keep things short, **how do I identify the button and it's event handler and textbox's text attribute in html, and where to a store the class files to make things work?**.

I already tried googling and Youtubing and I am not getting the results I'm looking for.

Edit: The previous question I asked involved using asp or aspx files which I don't think exist in my team projects. I'm using Visual Studio for all of this and unlike with forms I don't think or know that I can just click components to summon up its event-handlers.

Comment: So what i get is you want to conveet c# code to html?

Comment: well If I can keep the code as is and only change parts that say "buttonx_click" and "Textbox.Text" so that I don't have to start over that would be great. I am imagining that in the same way you can have a class that changes how a form behaves, that maybe the same can be done to html.

Comment: are you using JavaScript/jQuery on your web app. Or are you developing your app in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Your question is still not clear and i am having difficulty understanding it.

Comment: @progrAmmar, the app is being developed in ASP.Net Core.

I am being tasked with all the backend C# stuff while everyone else handles the layout.

Comment: @Steve How can I use C# with HTML? For example, say there is a html webpage with one button and one textbox, how can I make the button display "Hello World" to the textbox using C#.

Comment: Ok got it @kevin

Comment: In that case you can use the ASP.NET Text boxes and use Button_Click on ASP.NET core as well. Though for Text.Change you will have to implement either a POSTBACK or Ajax controls

Answer (score 1):

You should take any beginner to intermediate course or follow any tutorials to learn about asp.net/core MVC.

In asp.net core with MVC, 
You would have a view with .cshtml(your html file) extention and your controller having .cs extention (your class file) and a Model Class file.

For Example,
A simple controller might look like ,

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/

        public string Index()
        {
            return "Hello World !!";
        }

        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 

        public string welcome()
        {
            return "Welcome to .NET Core!!";
        }
    }
```

When you navigate to /helloworld you will see **Hello World!!** in your browser.
And when you navigate to /welcome it will display **Welcome to .NET Core**

You can find some tutorials [here](http://www.csharpstar.com/controllers-and-action-methods-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: thanks, I'm actually taking the college course right now which is what this is for, however things happened and my professor is absent half the time and I literally have days to finish this.

Comment: so I have this:`<button type="submit" OnClick="LogClick" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>` how do I make this button display something to a textbox in cshtml?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at JavaScript https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp or JQuery https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript in Body</h2>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```